Should I use INPlayMediaIntent or AppEntity + AudioPlaybackIntent for new apps?
WWDC videos suggest that existing apps should continue using the old SiriKit domains, such as INPlayMediaIntent. But what about new apps for playing audio? Should we implement Siri functionality for audio playback using the old SiriKit domains, or should we create our own AppEntities and trigger them via custom AudioPlaybackIntent implementations?
Interactive widgets require an AppIntent and don’t support the old INPlayMediaIntent. To achieve the same functionality as the Music app widgets, it seems logical to adopt the new AudioPlaybackIntent. However, I can't find any information about this in the documentation.
